# iOS UIView block animations stop actually animating

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

I've got a weird issue with using UIView block-based animations. My app contains an assortment of images in scroll views and, after a while of using the app on the device, all animations in UIView animation blocks (such as the one below) stop animating. The animation is processed (in the example code below, the pageView does move) but this change isn't animated and happens instantly.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
{ 
     self.pageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 704.0/2);
     self.pageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
} 
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
     NSLog(@"complete");
}];
```

Has anyone else experienced similar behaviour? I'm using an iPad on 5.1 and am wondering if it could be down to iOS version?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: I don't get if there are a lot of animations in your app running at the same time (what could be a reason) and if so, if more than one animation block is manipulating the same object.

Comment: It could be due to a number of animation blocks that could potentially be running at the same time. I'll try and see if that's the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your memory usage. I am seeing the same thing you are -- eventually all of the animations stopped working. The animations didn't even run for me, and completion blocks weren't firing.

I found that I was holding on to a number of UIImageViews that weren't visible anymore because I wanted to re-show them later. Removing them and freeing up the UIImage made the problem go away. I now need to figure out how I'm going to get back the images but at least the animations work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using transforms, animations can have a really unpredictable behavior if you use them separately. To avoid this, you ought to concatenate all your transforms into a single one via `CGAffineTransformConcat` and animate that single transform.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some animation options and see if that helps?

For example here I'm letting the user interact and letting views redraw themselves during an animation :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent   
                 animations:^ {
                    self.pageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 704.0/2);
                    self.pageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
               } completion:^ (BOOL finished) { 
               } ];
```

Comment: Thanks Dean. I'll give these a go.